# "None of [Index(['shares'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv that contains a dataset about a news popularity, I was trying to get the correlation for the `'shares'` column but I couldn't seem to get index it or the other columns as it displays the error code.

Here's a screenshot of the columns [image]

and I used these lines to check for the correlation.

```
    corr_check = whole.corr()
    corr_check
    print(corr_check["shares"])
```

Anyone knows how or why this happens?

Comment: Execute `print(corr_check.columns)`.

Comment: Thanks, it has a whitespace.